# Which database to use for storing key value (array) pairs

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database

Can someone please tell which database to use to store store key value pairs. I want my keys to be unicode string and value to be arrays of unicode strings. Should I use MySQL or MongoDB. I have read on wikipedia that MongoDB can store key value pairs. Also in MySQL I suppose I can store value as a blob. Please help. I am really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql is useful if you need to combine multiple related kinds of data. For example, if you have Users, Questions, Answers, and Comments. These are all related and need to be joined together.

MongoDB is useful when you have a single collection of data which does not need to be joined with other data. For example, Facebook has a nifty search box which populates as you type. These are just a list of names and ids, no need to join it with anything.